# jQuery is not working on Ajax infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using infinite Ajax scroll which loads pages by Ajax on scroll. Now I have to move some elements within each `li` element.

So jQuery is working properly with first page load, but not working on the page which is loaded by Ajax. In short it is working with the li elements which are by first time by page load but not working with li elements which are loaded by Ajax.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('.products.list li').each(function () {
    var discount = jQuery(this).find('span.discount');
    var luckycash = jQuery(this).find('span.rewards__product-points');
  });

  jQuery(this).find('.price-box.price-final_price').append(discount);
  jQuery(this).find('.price-box.price-final_price').append(luckycash);
});
```

Ajax infinite scroll js is https://github.com/manishjoy/magento2-catalog-infinite-scroll view/frontend/web/js/infinitescroll/jquery.ajaxscroll.min.js

Comment: more info needed, more script that is relevant, html,  is best if u can attached jsffidle

Comment: When do you execute the code in your question?

Comment: I can't make fiddle for this i am using extension for infinite scroll. I have put this code in the footer file.

Comment: that weird why it can't? because of the external js? you can use https://cdnjs.com/ to get the reference for the external js

Comment: Looks like a [`delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) issue... And where's the Ajax ? Why don't you post it?

Comment: Is that [this plugin](https://infiniteajaxscroll.com/) you're using ?

Comment: M using this https://github.com/manishjoy/magento2-catalog-infinite-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is certainly jquery event delegation issue:
Change your function like mentioned below. It should work.

```
jQuery(document).find('.products.list li').each(function () {  // Changed function syntax
    var discount = jQuery(this).find('span.discount');
    var luckycash = jQuery(this).find('span.rewards__product-points');
  });
```

Comment: I agree on the delegation thing... But what you suggest won't help. Suppose there is 10 `li`. That `.each()` loop defines the two variables 10 times... And then what? They hold the last jQuery elements... That's all. OP didn't provide enought about his code for anyone to answer, form my point of view.